# I want to add a text field by tapping the button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have already put the button and textfield on the storyboard.
I want to put a new textfield under it with code, but I don't know how.
Do you have a better way?
xcode12.2

```
@IBOutlet weak var kgTextField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repTextField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repTextField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repTextField3: UITextField!
    
    var addKgTextField : UITextField = UITextField()
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
addKgTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 60, height: 34)
    }
```

```
@IBAction func didTapAddSetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.addSubview(addKgTextField)
        self.view.reloadInputViews()
    }
```

Comment: If it's only one extra text field, you could create it in the storyboard as hidden and un-hide it when the button is tapped.

Comment: I didn't say.
There are many textfields I would like to add.
So I want to do it with code.

Comment: If it's limited by only one or two or even three but if it's a limited number you can put them all on stackView and make them hidden and by each click on the button you can unhide it and it will be shown by default in your code
and you have to make it in a scrollView to be able to add more

Comment: Thank you for your polite answer.
I didn't know how to do it.
However, there is no limit on the number.
I want a lot of textfields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solve your problem.

```
private var textFiled : UITextField{
    let field = UITextField()
    field.placeholder = "Email Address..."
    field.returnKeyType = .next
    field.leftViewMode = .always
    field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
    field.autocapitalizationType = .none
    field.autocorrectionType = .no
    field.layer.masksToBounds = true
    field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
    field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel.cgColor
    return field
}

var lastTextFiledFrame: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero

@IBAction func didTapAddSetButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let newTextFiled = self.textFiled
    view.addSubview(newTextFiled)
    newTextFiled.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: registerButton.bottom+10 + self.lastTextFiledFrame, width: view.width-40, height: 52)
    self.lastTextFiledFrame += newTextFiled.frame.height + 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add another Textfield and change its visibility when the button is pressed.

Comment: this should really be a comment so please explain using code how you would do that